# Android Studio "mikepenz materialdrawer" cannot find symbol class R [ release apk ]

Tags: java, android

so am working with mikepenz materialdrawer in my project and everything was fine and i was able to get Release apk from android studio

suddenly i have this error [ cannot find symbol class R ] when i try to get the release APK

gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sd.edu.oiu.medicine.mustafa"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.1'
    // Firebase
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

    compile project(":libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer")
    // used to showcase how to load images
    //compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    // used to generate the Open Source section
    // https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries
    compile('com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:5.7.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
        exclude module: "fastadapter"
    }
    //used to provide different itemAnimators for the RecyclerView
    //https://github.com/mikepenz/ItemAnimators
    compile 'com.mikepenz:itemanimators:0.2.4@aar'
    // used to provide the MiniDrawer to normal Drawer crossfade effect via a SlidingPane layout
    // --> https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/app/MiniDrawerActivity.java
    // https://github.com/mikepenz/Crossfader
    compile 'com.mikepenz:crossfader:1.3.7@aar'
    // used to provide the two step crossfade DrawerLayout. Which allows to have a mini layout which transforms to a normal layout within the drawer
    // --> https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/app/CrossfadeDrawerLayoutActvitiy.java
    // https://github.com/mikepenz/CrossfadeDrawerLayout
    compile('com.mikepenz:crossfadedrawerlayout:0.3.4@aar')

    // icon fonts used inside the sample
    // https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.4.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:octicons-typeface:3.0.0.1@aar'

    // Charts
    compile 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.0.10-SNAPSHOT@aar'
    //compile project(":libs:EazeGraph")
    //compile 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.2.2@aar'
    //compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
}
```

Error log

```
Information:Gradle tasks [assemble]
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23' in inconsistent location 'E:\Android\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23-1' (Expected 'E:\Android\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23')
Already observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23' in 'E:\Android\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23'. Skipping duplicate at 'E:\Android\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23-1'
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:compileLint
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:checkReleaseManifest
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2411Library UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72411Library UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2411Library UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72411Library UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42411Library UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2411Library UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:prepareComMikepenzFastadapter160Library UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:prepareComMikepenzIconicsCore267Library UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:prepareComMikepenzMaterialize090Library UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:prepareReleaseDependencies
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2411Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72411Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2411Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72411Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42411Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2411Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubBlackfizzEazegraph1010SNAPSHOTLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMikepenzAboutlibraries570Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMikepenzCrossfadedrawerlayout034Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMikepenzCrossfader137Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMikepenzFastadapter160Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMikepenzFontawesomeTypeface4401Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMikepenzGoogleMaterialTypeface2201Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMikepenzIconicsCore267Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMikepenzItemanimators024Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMikepenzMaterialize090Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMikepenzOcticonsTypeface3001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOIU_with_API_FinalLibsMikepenzMaterialDrawerUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\app\src\main\java\sd\edu\oiu\medicine\mustafa\RobotNoor.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 910 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug
:app:zipalignDebug
:app:assembleDebug
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:app:mergeReleaseShaders
:app:compileReleaseShaders
:app:generateReleaseAssets
:app:mergeReleaseAssets
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:processReleaseManifest
:app:processReleaseResources
:app:generateReleaseSources
:app:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\app\src\main\java\sd\edu\oiu\medicine\mustafa\RobotNoor.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseSources
:app:lintVitalRelease
:app:prePackageMarkerForRelease
:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease
:app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:app:packageRelease
:app:assembleRelease
:app:assemble
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:checkDebugManifest
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:prepareDebugDependencies
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:extractDebugAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:generateDebugJavadoc
100 warnings
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:jarDebugJavadoc
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:jarDebugSources
:libs:MikepenzMaterialDrawer:generateReleaseJavadoc
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\view\BezelImageView.java
Error:(50, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(50, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\holder\BadgeStyle.java
Error:(11, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(11, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\BaseViewHolder.java
Error:(8, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(8, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\ContainerDrawerItem.java
Error:(11, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(11, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\DividerDrawerItem.java
Error:(10, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(10, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\ExpandableDrawerItem.java
Error:(15, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(15, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\MiniDrawerItem.java
Error:(13, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(13, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\PrimaryDrawerItem.java
Error:(10, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(10, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\MiniProfileDrawerItem.java
Error:(15, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(15, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\ProfileSettingDrawerItem.java
Error:(19, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(19, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\SwitchDrawerItem.java
Error:(10, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(10, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\ToggleDrawerItem.java
Error:(10, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(10, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\SectionDrawerItem.java
Error:(12, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(12, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\util\DrawerItemViewHelper.java
Error:(8, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(8, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\util\DrawerUIUtils.java
Error:(16, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(16, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\AbstractDrawerItem.java
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\BaseDrawerItem.java
Error:(16, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\BasePrimaryDrawerItem.java
Warning:(54, 8) no description for @param
Warning:(54, 8) no description for @param
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\ProfileDrawerItem.java
Error:(21, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(21, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\SecondaryDrawerItem.java
Error:(6, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Warning:(29, 8) no description for @param
Warning:(30, 8) no description for @return
Error:(6, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Warning:(29, 8) no description for @param
Warning:(30, 8) no description for @return
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\SecondarySwitchDrawerItem.java
Error:(6, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Warning:(29, 8) no description for @param
Warning:(30, 8) no description for @return
Error:(6, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Warning:(29, 8) no description for @param
Warning:(30, 8) no description for @return
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\model\SecondaryToggleDrawerItem.java
Error:(6, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Warning:(29, 8) no description for @param
Warning:(30, 8) no description for @return
Error:(6, 35) error: cannot find symbol class R
Warning:(29, 8) no description for @param
Warning:(30, 8) no description for @return
E:\Projects\Android\OIU_with_API_Final\libs\MikepenzMaterialDrawer\src\main\java\com\mikepenz\materialdrawer\AccountHeader.java
```

Comment: Go to the `.java` files in the lib directory and delete all the imports like `android.support.design.R`.

Comment: Try clean project, see if it helps.

Comment: I tried to delete "import com.mikepepnz.materialdrawe.R",
Tried clean project, Tried rebuild project, Tried sync project with gradle

Non of above worked

Comment: Normally such issues come up when there are resource errors. or similar. what did you do prior to getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to delete "import com.mikepepnz.materialdrawe.R"
Tried clean project,
Tried rebuild project,
Tried sync project with gradle,

Non of above worked
The app run version work but gralde release versiom don't work

Answer (score 0):

Hover or Click on old package name in android studio.

Follow Steps:

> Ctrl + Shift + R

> Replace your new package name with old package name.

> File > Invalidate cache

Done!